# Duplicate Result When Trying To Fill Datagridview From Checklistbox With ValueMember And DisplayMember

Tags: c#

why this loop Return A Duplicate Result
Duplicate Result When Trying To Fill Datagridview From Checklistbox With ValueMember And DisplayMember

```
private void btn_ShowDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clb_SubItems.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (clb_SubItems.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                foreach (var item in clb_SubItems.CheckedItems.OfType<SP_SelectDriverItem_Result>())
                {
                    dgv_BOQItems.Rows.Add(item.SubCostItemID, clb_SubItems.GetItemText(clb_SubItems.Items[i]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because of the outer loop which you don't need here. You just need the inner `forreach` loop. See [CheckedListBox.CheckedItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider setting up the DataGridView with a preset columns and set the DataSource to a List.

Example

[image]

Backing class, ToString will be the DisplayMember of the CheckedListBox.

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

Mocked data

```
public class Mocked
{
    public static List<Company> Companies => new List<Company>()
    {
        new Company() {Id = 1, Name = "A"},
        new Company() {Id = 2, Name = "B"},
        new Company() {Id = 3, Name = "C"},
        new Company() {Id = 4, Name = "D"},
    };
}
```

Extension method to get checked companies in a CheckedListBox

```
public static class CheckedListBoxExtensions
{
    public static List<T> CheckedList<T>(this CheckedListBox source)
        => source.Items.Cast<T>()
            .Where((item, index) => source.GetItemChecked(index))
            .Select(item => item)
            .ToList();
}
```

Form

- One CheckedListBox
- One DataGridView with columns setup for Id and Name in Company class
- One button to get checked items and add each one if not currently in the DataGridView.

Code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    protected BindingList<Company> bindingList = new BindingList<Company>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }    
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource.DataSource = bindingList;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;

        checkedListBox1.DataSource = Mocked.Companies;
    }


    private void PopulateGridButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = checkedListBox1.CheckedList<Company>();

        if (result.Count <= 0) return;
        foreach (var company in result)
        {
            if (!bindingList.Contains(company))
            {
                bindingList.Add(company);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```